# Popup Box for button instead of a sentence

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm using:

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');">here</a> to see popup box one.</p>
    </div><!-- wrapper end -->
```

to create a link to my popupbox. (this works fine)

Now I want to use a button instead of the "here" part for the popupbox.
I've tried using:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="48px" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');" 
    Text="Button" />
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.

Can someone help me getting this button work?
The normal code for the button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="48px" onclick="Btn1_Click" 
    Text="Button" /
```

Comment: have you tried the onclientclick event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `onclick` to `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="48px" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');" 
Text="Button" />
```

when dealing with `<asp:` controls, unlike native html controls (such as `<a>` or `<input>`) you should use the proper attributes registered with ASP.NET.

when using `<asp:Button>`, the `onclick=` attribute actually refers to a **server side** method, and the `OnClientClick=` attribute refers to a **client side** method, which is what you're looking for in this case.

hope that helps.

Comment: It does work, but the popupbox directly closes. Do you know why it does close directly? Thanks btw.

Comment: can you show what's in `toggle_visibility` js method?

Comment: This is what I have atm in toggle_visibility:
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--3
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
   //-->
  </script>

Comment: is there any other event listener that triggers `toggle_visibility` ?

Comment: please try: `OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');return false;"`